# Two column align environment with one line spanning both columns

Tags: align, positioning, two-column

Is there a good/correct way of making an align environment with one line spanning multiple columns?

At the moment I'm using a hack like the following, but I feel that it's probably not the best way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 L1C1 &= 1234 \,,&     L1C2 &= abcd \,,\\
 L2C1 &= 1234 \,,&     L2C2 &= efgh \,,\\
 L3 &= 1234567890abcdefghijklmnop \ . \hspace{-30cm}
\end{align}    
\end{document}
```

[image: the result of above code]

Comment: another hack is to \rlap the part of the wider lines that would exceed the width of the first column. in the example given, i would, for the last line, put `L3 &= 1234567890\rlap{$abcdefghijklmnop \ .$}`. most lines of math contain reasonable places where one can break without damage.

Comment: @barbara: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is also a hack, but it will give the desired result.

use `\rlap` to "hide" the width of the overlong line.  for the example given, i would do this for the last line:

```
L3 &= 1234567890\rlap{$abcdefghijklmnop \ .$}
```

you might even want to put some extra space after that to get the desired separation; just look at the output to see what's needed.

most lines of math contain reasonable places where one can break without damage.

**Update:** 
In a comment, @user2478 has suggested using `\mathrlap`; requires `mathtools`.  (Yes, this is better than plain `\rlap`.)

Comment: with package `mathtools` one can write `\mathrlap{abcd...}`

Comment: I always forget the `*lap` commands (but for some reason `smash` stays in my head). @Herbert Thanks for the `mathrlap` command from `mathtools`. I think that's the cleanest solution given yet.

Comment: A much cleaner hack. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To span you could use `\span`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 L1C1 &= 1234 \,,&     L1C2 &= abcd \,,\\
 L2C1 &= 1234 \,,&     L2C2 &= efgh \,,\\
 L3 &= {}\span\omit$1234567890abcdefghijklmnop$\ .\hidewidth
\end{align}    
\end{document}
```

It turned out to be a lot more hacky than I initially thought it would be.

Comment: `\span` does not have the proper "class" for tex to be able to determine the spacing (see table, texbook, p.170).  if you precede `\span` by `{}` that would obviate the need for `\;`.

Comment: This changes the position of the equation numbering. [Here's a comparison](http://ifile.it/hp1adwg/ColumnSpanningForAlign.pdf).

Comment: @Simon: Edited.